# Windows XP - Data Recovery

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Windows XP OS

My Computer got infected by some virus and deleted most of the files in the Desktop.

Now, i am recovering the data from Hard Disk by connecting to an another Computer.

I am able to fetch the files from C:\

But, how to get the files from Desktop which got deleted. Is there anyway to retrieve from Recycle Bin? Where this Recycle bin is located in C:\ ?

Comment: They probably wouldn't be in your recycle bin, since they were not deleted in the usual manner (from a normal user session).  But if you want to check and be sure, the default location of the recycle bin on XP is c:\recycler.  This folder will be hidden so you might have to enable hidden files/folders to see it.  If you don't find the files in there, I have had luck with Active@ Undelete - third party disk recovery software.

Comment: @Chok : There is chance for converting your files to system files, these files will be hidden by default. Un check `Hide protected operating system files` from file and folder and search option and check whether your files is there on your desktop

Answer (score 2):

[Recuva is free](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) and may be able to find your files

[image]

Comment: care to explain how one might do that with Recuva?

Answer (score 0):

If they are deleted you can try a recovery tool for NTFS if you think they are on the recycle bin you should look for them on DRIVE:\$Recycle.Bin (replace DRIVE with C: or D: or whatever your disk is mounted on).

I would advise you try to recover your data from a Linux based operating system like Ubuntu you'll get less chances of getting a virus copy and you can also see hidden Windows files more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your user account temp folder, some malware moves all the Start menu items and desktop items in there, believe it or not. Look for numbered folders 1,2,3,4, etc